# Can't start a job with Cron on Ubuntu startup

Tags: ubuntu, cron, crontab

I am trying to get a simple Python script running on startup with Cron on Ubuntu 16.04.
What I did is opened cron with:
sudo crontab -e

and added the last line as shown in the screenshot:

[image]

Then I do:

```
sudo reboot
```

But when Ubuntu starts the Python file seems to have not run. It is supposed to create a text file. I have tested the Python script using the terminal and it successfully generates that text file.

Anyone know what I am missing here?

**Edit**: Following AFH's comment, I updated the line in crontab to this:

```
@reboot sudo /usr/bin/python /home/adi/pythons/python1.py
```

However, that didn't change anything at startup.

Comment: It looks basically OK, apart from the trailing `&`. I am not exactly sure of the effect of this: it may suspend it when the launching shell completes, so try without. It is also possible that `PATH` has not been set up, so type `which python` and use this full path in the `crontab` entry.

Comment: Yes, & is unnecessary but it just won't hurt.

Answer (score 0):

By calling `sudo crontab -e`, you edit the cron list of root. So there is no reason to use sudo in the cron entry. Of course, it's valid but if you do that, you have to have an entry in the sudoers file (`visudo` is the command to edit it) for the command to run and, since you cannot give any password for a process started by cron, you also must give ith the NOPASSWD tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to Linux. I just opened crontab with `crontab -e` and added `@reboot python /my_script_path &` there, but that didn't fix it. I also opened crontab with sudo and then passed `@reboot python /my_script_path &` there, but still the same thing. Can you please expand your ansewr a little more with details such as what I should add in visudo and where do I pass NOPASSWD?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to run the script as root, so you can just add it to /etc/rc.local, which is run by root at startup.

```
$sudo -i
#echo "/usr/bin/python /home/adi/pythons/python1.py" >> /etc/rc.local
#exit
```